# Does indexed search work in typo3 6.1?

Tags: search, typo3, templavoila

I have just finished migrating an old templavoila site to tyop3 6.1 and setup the indexed search (much like it was in 4.7) I can't get indexed search to index any content on any page. I would like to know if this extension actually works with a TV page and what I may have overlooked in it's setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

indexed_search is a core extension and always works on the current version. If you are using MySQL its also recommended to install index_search_mysql.

To activate indexing just set the options

```typoscript
config {
    #indexed_search
    index_enable = 1
}
```

And check the results in "Web > Info > Indexed Search". There are also scheduler tasks to clean up indexes.

Comment: Missed that and I had to enable the chash option on crawler before this would work. Also for people who are lost. Remember the config.no_cache in the root TS.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Merecs answer is wrong. You will have to set

`page.config.index_enable = 1`

for it to work.